# Vue 3 в БД прилетают не правильные данные

Tags: vue.js, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Столкнулся с проблемой с при вводе данных  через  v-model в базу записываются данные наоборот. к примеру если в инпут "telNumb" прилетает данные с инпута "name". при выводе в console.log() все стоит на своих местах

```
    <template>
  <form class="container" @submit.prevent>

    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">IP Address:</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input
            type="text"
            class="input"
            placeholder="New IP ADDRESS"
            v-model="editedHost.userIpAddr"

        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <label class="label"> User Name </label>
      <div class="control">
        <input
            type="text"
            class="input"
            v-model="editedHost.userName"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">location</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input
            type="text"
            class="input"
            placeholder="location"
            v-model="editedHost.userLocation"

        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">DEPT</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input
            type="text"
            class="input"
            placeholder="DEPT"
            v-model="editedHost.userPositionDept"


        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Password</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input
            type="text"
            class="input"
            placeholder="Password"
            v-model="editedHost.userPassword"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control">
      <button class="button is-success" @click="editHostIp">Обновить IP адрес</button>
      <button class="button is-warning ml-3" @click="$router.push('/dashboard')">Назад к списку</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "VueEditUserData",
  data: () => ({
    editedHost: {
      userIpAddr: "",
      userLocation: "",
      userName: "",
      userPassword: "",
      userPositionDept: "",
    },
  }),

  methods: {
    async fetchHostsById() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://192.168.32.17:3000/ipAddress/${this.$route.params.id}`)
        console.log(response)
      }catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }

    },
    async editHostIp() {
      await axios.put(`http://192.168.32.17:3000/ipAddress/${this.$route.params.id}`, {
        user_ipAddr: this.editedHost.userIpAddr,
        user_location: this.editedHost.userLocation,
        user_name: this.editedHost.userName,
        user_password: this.editedHost.userPassword,
        user_position_dept: this.editedHost.userPositionDept
      })
      console.log(this.editedHost)
    },
  },
  //
  // mounted() {
  //   this.editHostIp()
  // },
};
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: в editedHost данные точно правильно записываются, возможно на бэке вы ожидаете определенную последовательность параметров, а данные передаете по другому?

Comment: @TinaGordienko_Drog Думаю, если дело было бы в последовательности тогда я и при создании объекта получал такой же результат. И когда я обновляю объект через Postman у меня все правильно отрабатывает